# can't refer identifiers from .h file, when added directories in project properties

Tags: visual-c++

In project properties I've added .h folder to "Additional include Directories" and lib folder to "Additional Library Directories" and also lib file to "Additional dependencies".

However I still can not use identifiers from .h file. I receive "Identifier is undefined" and I do not see .h file in "External Dependencies".

What else should I do?

Why I do not see .h files from the folder I've added to "Additional include Directories" in the "External Dependencies"?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that i've to add `#include <neededlibrary.h>`. Once such line is added to cpp file the required file is automatically placed to external dependencies.